# Error: Cannot find module '/usr/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js' when trying to dockerize a NestJs Project

Tags: docker, nestjs

I'm trying to dockerize a NestJS application but I'm being block by this error.

I try to yarn add global @nestjs/cli on my local machine and on the container.

I have the following code in my Dockerfile:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:19.8.1-alpine as development

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN yarn global add @nestjs/cli
RUN yarn install --only=development

COPY . .

RUN yarn build

FROM node:12.19.0-alpine3.9 as production

ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --only=production

COPY . .

COPY --from=development /usr/src/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "dist/main"]
```

This is the code in my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    dev:
        container_name: nestjs_api_dev
        image: nestjs-api-dev:1.0.0
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
            command: yarn start
        ports:
            - 3000:3000
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nesjs-network
        volumes:
            - /usr/src/app/node_modules
        restart: unless-stopped
```

The error I'm getting whn I'm trying to docker-compose up dev:

```
0.776 $ nest build
0.834 node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1093
0.834   throw err;
0.834   ^
0.834
0.834 Error: Cannot find module 
'/usr/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/bin/nest.js'
0.834     at Module._resolveFilename 
(node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1090:15)
0.834     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:934:27)
0.834     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] 
(node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
0.834     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
0.834   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
0.834   requireStack: []
0.834 }
0.834
0.834 Node.js v19.8.1
0.854 error Command failed with exit code 1.
0.854 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Why do you mount an anonymous volume over the image's `node_modules` directory?  Does deleting the `volumes:` block help at all?  The error screen shot is hard to read; can you [edit] the question to include it in plain text?

Comment: I included the plain text of the error. I tried to remove the volumes but I still got the same error.

Comment: @BenjoeCarandang did you solve this problem finally?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, I changed the location of WORKDIR from /usr/src/app to /app and then also added the global install command in my docker file:

```
RUN npm install -g @nestjs/cli
```